# Class cast exception: cannot convert from Checkboxpreference to SwitchPreference

Tags: android, preferenceactivity, checkboxpreference

I am not able to identify the issue with my code and it seems no one face this kind of issue, so not able to track this in stack overflow.

Exception message:

```
Caused by: java.lang.ClassCastException: android.preference.CheckBoxPreference cannot be cast to android.preference.SwitchPreference
```

**Code:**

```
private Preference preference;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
{
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    getSupportActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);
    addPreferencesFromResource(R.xml.settings);
    loadAllViews();
}

private void loadAllViews()
{
   if (VERSION.SDK_INT >= VERSION_CODES.ICE_CREAM_SANDWICH)
   {
        preference = (SwitchPreference) findPreference("preference"); //Exception occurs here.
   }
   else
   {
        preference = (CheckBoxPreference) findPreference("preference");
   }
}

__________________    __________________    __________________
```

settings.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<PreferenceScreen xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" >

    <CheckBoxPreference
        android:key="preference"
        android:title="yes_or_no" />

</PreferenceScreen>
```

Some one please help me to figure it out.

Comment: both your switch and checkbox preferences are named preference. CHange that

Comment: Sorry I am not able to understand, please elaborate..  @AtulOHolic

Comment: Do u have a layout for your SwitchPreference like you have for your CheckboxPreference like <CheckBoxPreference
        android:key="preference"
        android:title="yes_or_no" />

Comment: @down voter. Please tell me, if I am doing anything wrong. or if it is duplicated.

Comment: got it..  thanks a lot..  I need to create it.. under xml-v14 directory..

Comment: great, cheers :) n i didnt downvote.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Need to have two separate layout.

One for check preference at layout directory.

And another for SwitchPreference at layout-v14 directory.

Answer (score 3):

`CheckBoxPreference` does not `extends` `SwitchPreference`; hence it cannot be cast to it. Both of these classes are children of `TwoStatePreference`.

From your code, it seems that you are referencing one preference key for two different preference components:

```
  if (VERSION.SDK_INT >= VERSION_CODES.ICE_CREAM_SANDWICH)
   {
        preference = (SwitchPreference) findPreference("preference"); //Exception occurs here.
   }
   else
   {
        preference = (CheckBoxPreference) findPreference("preference");
   }
```

As you can see, this will work fine for the correct preference type, but it will throw a `ClassCastException` for the incorrect type. Make sure you are referencing the correct key for the correct `TwoStatePreference`.

Comment: But either SwitchPreference or CheckBoxPreference will be working at a time. so I hope that won't be an issue.  Please Correct me what I am doing wrong.  @Emmanuel

Comment: Each preference should have its own key. You should give the `SwitchPreference` one key and `CheckBoxPreference` another key. Keys should be unique. Now you are calling both "preference"

Comment: No problem, glad to help. Please mark this question as answered.

Answer (score 0):

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
```

```
<SwitchPreference
    android:key="preference1"
    android:title="yes_or_no" />

<CheckBoxPreference
    android:key="preference2"
    android:title="yes_or_no" />
```

In the code:
Preference preference;

if (VERSION.SDK_INT >= VERSION_CODES.ICE_CREAM_SANDWICH)
   {
        preference = (SwitchPreference) findPreference("preference1");
   }
   else 
   { 
        preference = (CheckBoxPreference) findPreference("preference2");
   }